# Sigma notation using Modulo

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic

I've come across a step in a proof in a book on number theory that doesn't make sense to me:

$$\sum_{n(mod\,p)}\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{p}$$
$$=\sum_{n(mod\,p)}\frac{(n+1)(n)(n+2)}{p}$$

As I understand it, using notation like $n(mod\;p)$ as a sigma range should be equivalent to:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{p}$$

But, assuming this, the second line above doesn't seem to follow.

Am I misinterpreting the notation or is there something subtler going on here?

Comment: It probably means the sum is done over the ring $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Hence you don't change the sum if you add one to each occurence of $n$. But then, $1/p$ is not well defined, since it's congruent to $0$. Bad notation.

Comment: @Arbaut I have thought that, but what sense has that fraction (that is not an integer and its denominator is precisely $p$) mod $p$?

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes, I saw this as an afterthought. Very strange!

Comment: So do you mean to say that the n(mod p) not only makes stipulations about the range for the sum, but also the values of n in the function the sum is summing across? Aka, it means sum from n = 0 to p-1 and also to replace each instance of n in the n(n-1)(n+1)/p with n(mod p)?